# Starting Pact server throws Pact Binary Error

Tags: karma-jasmine, pact

I want to create consumer Pact tests in Angular.

I have put pact dependencies in package.json:

```
   "@pact-foundation/karma-pact": "2.1.9",
   "@pact-foundation/pact-node": "6.21.3",
   "@pact-foundation/pact-web": "7.2.0",
```

Then I updated my karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular', 'pact'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'),
            require('@pact-foundation/karma-pact')
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
            reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        },
        angularCli: {
            environment: 'prod'
        },
        // load pact web module
        files: [
            '../node_modules/@pact-foundation/pact-web/pact-web.js'
        ],
        pact: [{
            cors: true,
            port: 1235,
            consumer: "ui",
            provider: "testservice",
            dir: "pacts",
            spec: 2
        }],
        proxies: {
            '/test-service/': 'http://127.0.0.1:1235/test-service/'
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
        port: 9876,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,
        autoWatch: true,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
        singleRun: true
    });
};
```

Now when I start ng test, Karma tries to start Pact server and throws an error:

```
07 02 2019 16:14:23.694:DEBUG [plugin]: Loading inlined plugin (defining framework:pact).
 10% building modules 2/2 modules 0 active[2019-02-07T15:14:23.890Z]  INFO: pact-node@6.21.3/16304 on VAA6DAB0246:
    Creating Pact Server with options: 
    cors = true,
    port = 1235,
    consumer = ui,
    provider = testservice,
    dir = D:\Users\aster\WebstormProjects\test\pacts,
    spec = 2,
    pactFileWriteMode = overwrite,
    ssl = false,
    host = localhost
[2019-02-07T15:14:23.905Z]  INFO: pact-node@6.21.3/16304 on VAA6DAB0246: Created 'standalone\win32-1.63.0\bin\pact-mock-service.bat service --cors 'true' --port '1235' --consumer 'ui' --provider 'testservice' --pact_dir 'D:\Users\aster\WebstormProjects\test\pacts' --pact_specification_version '2' --pact-file-write-mode 'overwrite' --host 'localhost'' process with PID: 35496
[2019-02-07T15:14:31.221Z] ERROR: pact-node@6.21.3/16304 on VAA6DAB0246:
    Pact Binary Error: Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

[2019-02-07T15:14:31.482Z]  WARN: pact-node@6.21.3/16304 on VAA6DAB0246: Pact exited with code 1.
[2019-02-07T15:14:31.482Z]  INFO: pact-node@6.21.3/16304 on VAA6DAB0246: Removing Pact with PID: 35496
FEHLER: Der Prozess "35496" wurde nicht gefunden.                                                                                                                                                     07 02 2019 16:14:53.913:ERROR [pact]: Error while trying to run karma-pact: Error: Couldn't start Pact with PID: 35496
```

Does anybody know, how to fix this error? Or maybe has ideas how to find out what path is missing?

Comment: As you might have guessed, Pact starts another file from node_modules to do some of this work. Are you able to manually find and run pact-mock-service.bat? If you can run this, then there might be an issue in the way the binary is being spawned by the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a reason of this error - our enterprise firewall has blocked the download of binaries. I have downloaded binaries manually and now pact works without errors.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue as well (using Mac OS) and adding my hostname as an alias in the  hosts file solved this problem.

You can find out your hostname by running `hostname` in the terminal.It will be something like `mymacbook.local`.

Then add/edit these entries in the `/etc/hosts` file so that they look like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost mymacbook.local
::1         localhost mymacbook.local
```

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the same problem. As stated in Ilja's answer the binary had to be downloaded. Also "pact_binary_location" had to be configured in package.json.
This is well described on https://www.npmjs.com/package/@pact-foundation/pact-node